# Android: SurfaceView surfaceChanged Center in Parent

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, surfaceview

I am creating an application that takes an image and centers it onscreen for alteration. I am using a SurfaceView and Canvas. I am trying to center the SurfaceView in the parent RelativeLayout. I had it working, but it would become distorted on rotate. So I am currently using the surfaceChanged method to reset the size of the bitmap and canvas when the orientation changes:

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged (SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        bitmap_width = height * imageRatio;
        bitmap_height = height;
    } else {
        bitmap_width = width;
        bitmap_height = width / imageRatio;
    }

    canvas_width = (int) bitmap_width;
    canvas_height = (int) bitmap_height;

    try {
        canvas_bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(initial_bitmap, (int) bitmap_width, (int) bitmap_height, true);
        surface_canvas = new Canvas();
        surface_canvas.setBitmap(canvas_bitmap);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The scaling now works, but now it is not centered. I also noticed that the rest of the background is black, not gray as it used to be. This would lead me to believe that the canvas is stretched beyond the view of the bitmap. Upon further inspection I noticed that the surfaceChanged method gets called twice when started. So I started Logging everything, and this is what I found:

```
07-27 16:39:21.363    2129-2129/com... E/SURFACE_CHANGED﹕ imageRatio: 1.3333334 width: 1080 height: 1701 bitmap_width: 1080.0 bitmap_height: 810.0 canvas_width: 1080 canvas_height: 810 surface_width: -1 surface_height: -2

07-27 16:39:21.388    2129-2129/com... E/SURFACE_CHANGED﹕ imageRatio: 0.0 width: 1080 height: 1701 bitmap_width: 1080.0 bitmap_height: Infinity canvas_width: 1080 canvas_height: 2147483647 surface_width: -1 surface_height: -2
```

Most importantly the imageRatio, which is only set once in my code, changes to 0.0. Thus setting one either the height or the width of the bitmap to Infinity. If I rotate the device, a similar set of two logs appear, with the original imageRatio set to 1.33... and then changing to 0.0. I cannot for the life of me figure out why this would be the case.

Anyway, this is easily avoided. I wrapped my code it an if statement specifying (imageRatio > 0.0). Yet the issue persists, nothing changes!

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is. The last half of your question is concerned with imageRatio, but you don't show where or how that is set. I'm also puzzled about the Canvas you're creating -- how are you drawing on the SurfaceView?

Comment: @fadden Sorry I wasn't very clear. Honestly it's really two questions; 1. Why is the imageRatio changed? And 2. How can I make the canvas and SurfaceView centered on screen?

Comment: @fadden As for how I am setting the imageRatio, it is declared as a local variable at the start of the class. It is only set once, when I set the Bitmap to use as the background from the previous activity: `public void setBitmap (Bitmap bitmap) {
        initial_bitmap = bitmap;
        imageRatio = (float) bitmap.getWidth() / bitmap.getHeight();
    }` And the draw method takes the canvas_bitmap that is set in surfaceChanged and draws it to the canvas: `@Override
    public void draw (Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        canvas.drawBitmap(canvas_bitmap, matrix, paint);
    }`

Comment: Wow, never mind... I answered my own first question. I had another class that I had forgotten I created for later use that extended my first SurfaceView class, and didn't override the surfaceChanged method. That was the cause of the imageRatio problem. But still doesn't fix the real issue, how to get the SurfaceView centered on screen. I have tried changing the LayoutParams, but that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Take a look at how Grafika adjusts the View size to match the video aspect ratio -- the custom FrameLayout approach might be what you need. https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/PlayMovieSurfaceActivity.java (search for "aspect", and look at the XML layout to see how it's applied).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out. The width and the height of the actual SurfaceView was not changing to match the size of the bitmap, so I had to change the size of the SurfaceView before surfaceChanged got called. So I overrode onConfigurationChanged to change the size of the SurfaceView itself with surfaceHolder.setFixedSize(), which ends up calling surfaceChanged anyway:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);

    int screenWidth = screenSize.x;
    int screenHeight = screenSize.y;
    float width;
    float height;

    if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        screenHeight = screenSize.x;

        width = screenHeight * imageRatio;
        height = screenHeight;
    } else if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        screenWidth = screenSize.x;

        width = screenWidth;
        height = screenWidth / imageRatio;
    } else {
        Log.e("UNSUPPORTED_ORIENTATION", Integer.toString(config.orientation));
        width = screenWidth;
        height = screenHeight;
    }

    surfaceHolder.setFixedSize((int) width, (int) height);
}
```

Then I used surfaceChanged to set the width and height of the canvas and bitmap to match the surfaceView:

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged (SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    bitmapWidth = width;
    bitmapHeight = height;

    canvasWidth = width;
    canvasHeight = height;

    try {
        canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(initialBitmap, (int) bitmapWidth, (int) bitmapHeight, true);
        surfaceCanvas = new Canvas();
        surfaceCanvas.setBitmap(canvasBitmap);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear: `setFixedSize()` changes the size of the Surface. The layout code changes the size of the View. The hardware scales whatever you draw on the Surface to fit the View.  (Demo here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qpRaD-ij2xc )